# Two-way arrows possible in force directed graph?

Tags: d3.js, directed-graph, force-layout

I have created a graph similar to this force directed graph: http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/5141278 :

[image]

Using the link as an example: Sarah is linked to James and James is linked to Sarah. Instead of cluttering up the page with two arrows (one in each direction), is there a way to make it have just one arrow with triangles on both ends?

Comment: Hi! can you tell me if you have this example but with rect instead of circles? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

All you have to do to achieve this is add another marker to the links:

```
var path = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("path")
  .data(force.links())
  .enter().append("svg:path")
  .attr("class", "link")
  .attr("marker-end", "url(#end)")
  .attr("marker-start", "url(#end");
```

Example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/larskotthoff/7830074). This doesn't work perfectly though because of the way the [SVG spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/painting.html#OrientAttribute) specifies how the direction the arrow is pointing in should be computed, in particular:

> If there is only a path segment going out of the vertex (e.g., the first vertex on an open path), the marker's positive x-axis should point in the same direction as the tangent vector for the path segment going out of the vertex. (Refer to ‘path’ element implementation notes for a more thorough discussion of the directionality of path segments.)

In those cases, you could calculate and specify the angle of the arrow yourself to fix the orientation.

Comment: I attempted to add this and unfortunately I still had two lines and now an additional arrow on the other side of my node. I've created a jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6w2La

Comment: Yes, this is, as I've said, due to the SVG spec. There's no easy way around this apart from drawing a second (identical) line in the opposite direction to give the impression of one line with the arrows pointing in the right direction.

Comment: I assume you were editing your answer as I was posting my comment (I added my comment before the edited portion of your answer appeared on my screen - wasn't ignoring what you had written). I think I may see if adding arrows to an example like this (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2706022) will work better...

Comment: Rather than draw a second line, I ended up just getting rid of the curvature of the line. See adjusted tick function below:

    function tick() {
    path.attr("d", function(d) {
        var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
            dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
            dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
        return "M" + 
            d.source.x + "," + 
            d.source.y + " " +  
            d.target.x + "," + 
            d.target.y;
    });

Here is the updated fiddle to view results: http://jsfiddle.net/6w2La/2/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today. I wanted two arrows with different directions on one link. The solution is simple, just change the path of the shape.

So first create two arrow defs:

```
vis.append("defs").selectAll("marker")
    .data(["arrow"])
    .enter().append("marker")
    .attr("id", "markerEnd")
    .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
    .attr("refX", 19)
    .attr("refY", -0,7)
    .attr("markerWidth", 6)
    .attr("markerHeight", 6)
    .attr('markerUnits', "userSpaceOnUse")
    .attr("orient", "auto")
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

vis.append("defs").selectAll("marker")
    .data(["arrow"])
    .enter().append("marker")
    .attr("id", "markerStart")
    .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
    .attr("refX", -12)
    .attr("refY", -0,7)
    .attr("markerWidth", 6)
    .attr("markerHeight", 6)
    .attr('markerUnits', "userSpaceOnUse")
    .attr("orient", "auto")
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", "M0,0L10,-5L10,5Z");
```

As you can see, one is called "markerStart" and one "markerEnd", they are now in the opposite direction.

The path looks like this then:

```
hlink.enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "hlink")
    .attr("marker-start", "url(#markerStart)")
    .attr("marker-end", "url(#markerEnd)");
```